# A die is tossed 1000 times . Compute $P(x\ge170)$ and $P(162\le x\le 171)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Could someone check my solution and tell me what am I doing wrong in the second probability?

Thank you.

> A dice is tossed 1000 times. Lex $x$ be the number of times of getting 4 points. Compute $P(x\ge170)$ and $P(162\le x\le 171)$.

Solution.

- As $x\ge30,$ $x$ can be approximated to a normal distribution with $\mu=1000/6$ and $\sigma^2=5000/36.$

Thus $P(x\ge170)=1-P(x<170)=1-P(z<.2835)=.3936$

- And $P(162\le x\le 171)=P(-.3960<z<.3680)=P(z<.3680)-P(z>-.3960)=.6368-[1-P(z<-.3960)]=.6368-[1-.3520]<0$ which is not correct, must be between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked everything, but
there is an error in this line
$$
P(-.3960<z<.3680)=P(z<.3680)-P(z>-.3960)
$$
The final term should be 
$$
P(z\lt-.3960)
$$
i.e.
$$
P(-.3960\lt z \lt .3680)=P(z \lt .3680)-P(z\lt-.3960)
$$

Comment: What do you mean you have not checked everything? My solution migth be wrong due numerical calculations or due wrong method solution?

Comment: "I haven't checked everything" usually means "I checked it until I found the first mistake".

Comment: @gnasher729 but the first mistake is in the last part of the solution, so he checked the whole answer. But then his/her comment 
"I haven't checked everything" doesn't make sense.

Comment: It sounds like a quibble Alt.  Gnasher gave you the right formula.  All that is left is to plug in the numbers.for the probabilities.

Comment: @Al t. It was asked what was wrong with the 2nd probability. I did not check your $\mu $ or $\sigma^2$ or conversion to $z $ but found a fundamental error in the working . I hoped showing you that error would be of some help to you.

Comment: yes of course your help was useful. Thank you .  I just hope the method used to solve the general problem is correct